# Como coloco um limite de caracter no input TextField

Tags: react

```
 <TextField
    key={property}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    multiline
    rows={10}
    inputProps={{ maxLength: 200 }}
    onChange={onHandleChange}
    defaultValue={tool?.[property] || undefined}
  />
```

O maxLength que coloquei limitou, só que preciso que apareça para o usuario aquele campo que vai mostrando os caracteres, assim:
[exemplo de como preciso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hHSz.png)

Estou utilizando React, e mui material

Comment: É só criar um `<span>` com o valor de `{{ value.length }} / 200`, sendo `value` o objeto de valor do seu campo.

Comment: Acho que a prop `helperText` é mais apropriada para isso.

Answer (score 0):

vc pode utilizar a propriedade InputProps para incluir um componente personalizado como endAdornment. Isso permite que vc exiba um contador de caracteres na parte inferior direita do campo

exemplo:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

function MyTextField() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      label="Digite algo"
      multiline
      rows={4}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <div>{value.length} / 200</div>
        ),
        inputProps: {
          maxLength: 200
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

aqui há um estado para armazenar o valor do TextField. Em handleChange, atualizamos o valor do estado com o valor digitado pelo usuario

incluímos um div como endAdornment na propriedade InputProps. A div exibe o número atual de caracteres e o número máximo permitido.

para limitar os caracteres, definimos maxLength em inputProps, assim o navegador restringe a entrada do usuário ao número máximo especificado